# Junk values in dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic

Could somebody help me figure why I am getting junk values in my array? My code is:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

char buffer[5000];
int size = 0;
char *ptr;
char **fileArrayPTR;

fileArrayPTR = malloc(sizeof(char*));

while (fgets(buffer, 5001, fp) != NULL) {
    fileArrayPTR[size] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    strcpy(fileArrayPTR[size], buffer);
    for (int p = 0; p < 5001; p++) {
        if (fileArrayPTR[size][p] == '\n') {
            fileArrayPTR[size][p] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    //printf("%s\n",fileArrayPTR[size]);
    size++;
}
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    printf("%s\n", fileArrayPTR[x]);
}
```

If I uncomment the the printf statement in front of the `size++`, I get the right result, but when I take that out and try the bottom part of the code it doesn't work. It works for `fileArrayPTR[16]` or higher but not from 0-15. Also if I was to return `fileArrayPTR` to `main`, how could I also return the size as well?

Comment: Take a closer look at your first `malloc` call.

Comment: `fileArrayPTR = malloc(sizeof(char*));`  : `fileArrayPTR` can hold only one pointer. you can use only `fileArrayPTR[0]`. Also `5001` --> `5000`

Comment: I changed my code to fileArrayPTR = malloc(5000 * sizeof(char*)) and it works (the same of the buffer). Should I keep this, is it proper coding convention?

Comment: @FreeStyle4: it works because your file has fewer than 5001 lines.  You just reallocate the string array.

Comment: `fgets(buffer,5001,fp)` : Buffer size is larger than the actual one. change to `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)`

Comment: The `p` loop should stop when it reaches `'\0'` otherwise you are reading uninitialized values (probably UB)

Answer (score 0):

You should reallocate the string array to grow it as more lines are read:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **getlines(int *sizep) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[5001];
    int size = 0;
    char **fileArrayPTR = NULL;

    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        *sizep = -1;
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, 5001, fp) != NULL) {
        fileArrayPTR = realloc(fileArrayPTR, sizeof(*fileArrayPTR) * (size + 1));
        fileArrayPTR[size] = strdup(buffer);
        for (int p = 0; p < 5001; p++) {
            if (fileArrayPTR[size][p] == '\n') {    
                fileArrayPTR[size][p] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
        //printf("%s\n", fileArrayPTR[size]);
        size++;
    }
    *sizep = size;
    return fileArrayPTR;
}

int main(void) {
    int size;
    char **array = getlines(&size);
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[x]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `buffer` should be defined with a size of `5001` for consistency with the rest of the code.

You can return the `size` to `main` by setting a variable to which you pass a pointer, as shown above.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: oops! fixed. I updated the code with proper prototype and a main function.

Comment: It had better be `free` for beginners ：）

Comment: When I call char**array = getlines(&size), it returns back 0 for the size

Comment: @FreeStyle4: this would indicate that the file `input.txt` is empty.

Comment: in the getlines function when I have *sizep = &size. Then when I print the size, printf("%d",*sizep). I get the correct size (34). When I try printing the size in main I get 0

Comment: @FreeStyle4: in `getlines`, the code is `*sizep = size;`, not `*sizep = &size`.